# Reactive UI Getting started with compelling example wont work

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I did this many times, but now it just doest work.

I am following this example:
https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/

I have my MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using ReactiveUI;

namespace KardexTerminal_WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<MainViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<rxui:ReactiveWindow x:Class="KardexTerminal_WPF.MainWindow"
         xmlns:rxui="https://reactiveui.net" 
        x:TypeArguments="local:MainViewModel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KardexTerminal_WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveWindow>
```

MainViewModel:

```
using ReactiveUI;

namespace KardexTerminal_WPF
{
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, IScreen
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Router = new RoutingState();
        }

        public RoutingState Router { get; }
    }
}
```

Simple as documentation suggest. This is completely new project and have only ReactiveUI and ReactiveUI.WPF packages installed.

But I am getting those error:
[image: Errors]
[image: Errors]

I will be glad for any help, if anyone knows what is the issue.

**EDIT 1:
If I implement IViewFor, then it works.**

I have tried suggestions from comments on view usercontrol:

```
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl x:Class="KardexTerminal_WPF.Views.LoginView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KardexTerminal_WPF.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:KardexTerminal.ViewModels;assembly=KardexTerminal"
             x:TypeArguments="vm:LoginViewModel"
             xmlns:rxui="https://reactiveui.net"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
            
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>
```

```
namespace KardexTerminal_WPF.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LoginView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LoginView
    {
        public LoginView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

But that makes those errors, I am not sure what is wrong:
[image]

I am using those packages:
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Answer below from @mm8 helped to make the program compile.
ReactiveUI has wrong documentation and should be fixed:
https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/

But there is stil error, which I cannot seem to get rid off. I will proceed with that at GitHub issue.

[image: Persisting error]

Comment: I usually avoid to use the `ReactiveWindow<T>` inheritance and prefer the implementation of the `IViewFor<T>` interface since the first errors are quite common, therefore if they put it in the examples these should work. If you want I've made some workaround

Comment: Answer is a lot simpler then it seems, remove the base class in your .xaml.cs file in the code behind. Partial classes only need to declare the base class once which is done in your xaml. Have just `public partial class MainWindow` instead of the ReactiveWindow.

Comment: @StefanoCavion The approach you've taken is not required for WPF. Definitely required for UWP.

Comment: @GlennWatson So what should I do? For every user control and view implement manually IViewFor? This used to work, but it doesnt work either with ReactiveUserControl.

Comment: @GlennWatson I have made edit to the OP trying your suggestion.

Comment: I never got RxUI's Routing example to work.  I changed `MainViewModel.GoBack` from `public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> GoBack { get; }` to `public ReactiveCommand<Unit, IRoutableViewModel> GoBack { get; }` since `RoutingState.NavigateBack` expects those args, and `GoBack` is set to that command.  But `MainViewModel` is not derived from `IRoutableViewModel` (`FirstViewModel` is) so perhaps not that surprising that the `GoBack` button doesn't work.  Never did find a solution.  @GlennWatson, do you believe the example actually works? No dis to ReactiveUI, which is clearly a thing of beauty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace is **http:**//reactiveui.net (and not https://...):

```
xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
```

Besides this, your code-behind class should inherit from `ReactiveUserControl<LoginViewModel>` since this is the base class you have specified in the XAML markup:

```
public partial class LoginView : ReactiveUserControl<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: The https helped it to compile, but they should really fox that in documentantion: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar problems using the `ReactiveUserControl` class. I've found 2 workaround for this

1)Create a base class for your window that inherit from `ReactiveWindow` than let `MainWindow` inherit from that class

```
 public class MainWindowBase : ReactiveWindow<MainViewModel> { }

 /// <summary>
 /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
 /// </summary>
 public partial class MainWindow 
 { 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

Than in your xaml

```
<local:MainWindowBase x:Class="YourNameSpace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" Height="600" Width="1000" >
```

2)Implement manually the `IViewFor<T>`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(MainViewModel), typeof(MainWindow));

        public MainViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (MainViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
        }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get => ViewModel;
            set => ViewModel = (MainViewModel)value;
        }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       }
```

EDIT: based on the comment of Glenn Watson I've updated the answer but for completeness I'll add here the previous answer that will be usefull when working on the  UWP

```
public class MainWindowBase : ReactiveWindow<MainViewModel> { }

 /// <summary>
 /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
 /// </summary>
 public partial class MainWindow :MainWindowBase 
 { 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

Comment: The issue is actually the derived class. You don't need derived class declaration operator in the `.xaml.cs` file. So this solution is actually overkill for WPF. UWP had a earlier version of xaml which couldn't handle generic overloads which is why this solution is the valid one for UWP.

Comment: @GlennWatson I'll give it a try and let you know ;)

Comment: @GlennWatson yep you are totally right it doesn't need the derived class operator in the `.xaml.cs` so let me update the answer